# C Sockets: accept() always returns the same socket ID?

Tags: c, sockets

accept is always returning the same socket ID / file descriptor (connfd: 4)

No matter if I'm on the same local machine using two different processes or on two separate machines. Why aren't the return values different?

Not sure if it has something to do with the output. I used to just use printf() but no output would go on stdout so I changed it to fprintf(stderr, ...). I also tried using fflush(), same thing, same socket ID/descriptor from accept()

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h> /* -pthread */

#define SERVER_PORT 5000

void *cli_func(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        fflush(stdout);
        int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

        char sendBuff[1025];
        time_t ticks;
        listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        fprintf(stderr, "Starting server...\n");

        memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
        memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff));

        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

        bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

        listen(listenfd, 10);

        fprintf(stderr, "Listening...\n");

        while(1){

                connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
                pthread_t cli_thread;
                fprintf(stderr, "Got new client\n");

                if(pthread_create(&cli_thread, NULL, cli_func, &connfd)){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
                        return 1;
                }
                /*
                if(pthread_join(cli_thread, NULL)){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
                        return 2;
                }
                */
                ticks = time(NULL);
                snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
                write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));

                close(connfd);

                sleep(1);

        }

}

void *cli_func(void *arg){
        int* clifd_ptr = (int *)arg;
        fprintf(stderr, "client ID: %d", *clifd_ptr);

        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: It returns the lowest available file descriptor. Once you `close` it, it becomes available again.

Comment: Why does it matter what the value of the fd is? It's most likely going to be an index into some opaque per-process table.

Comment: But when I do write(), how do I specify which client to write to if it's the same fd value for both clients?

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that you're `accept`ing the connection and spinning off a thread to service it (I assume that's what `cli_thread` is eventually intended to do), but then your main thread is closing the file descriptor.

Different threads in the same process share the same file descriptors. If you close it in the main thread, your other thread cannot then use it.

This is different than `fork`. When you fork, you're creating a separate process -- that process gets a copy of each file descriptor *at the time of the fork* so then it's fine to close the file descriptor in the main process after you've spun off the child process (it will remain open in the child).

Whether forking or creating a thread, it's probably a bad idea to write to the socket in the main thread *after* spinning off the child process / service thread. By doing that, you've created a race. Most of the time, the parent / main thread will get to the `write` call before the child / service thread. But occasionally due to random events (interrupts / pre-emption by other processes), the child or service thread will get fully started and reach its own write first. That will potentially leave the peer not knowing what to expect next (assuming that makes a difference in your protocol).

One more thing, it's a bad practice and dangerous to pass the *address* of `conn_fd` to the service thread. `conn_fd` is a local variable in your main thread. Were your main thread to return, the pointer you've given to the service thread is now pointing to stack space that has likely been re-used and who knows what will be stored there.

You can instead pass the `conn_fd` value directly to the service thread by casting it appropriately:

```
pthread_create(&cli_thread, NULL, cli_func, (void *)(uintptr_t)connfd)
```

Then in the service thread:

```
void *cli_func(void *arg){
    int conn_fd = (uintptr_t)arg;
```

(`uintptr_t` is declared in `<stdint.h>` and is guaranteed to be an integer of the same size as a pointer so using it as intermediary prevents the gcc complaint about casting from pointer to an integer of a different size [or vice versa].)

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes so much sense. Question though, why does it matter if I just pass in an int? Why does it need to be cast to uintptr_t? Can't I just specify in the thread function that the argument could be int and just pass in an int value directly?

Comment: Most compilers will at least warn you about passing the wrong type (if not producing an actual error) -- and it is considered good practice to make one's code free of warnings. Also pointer-integer / integer-pointer conversions are "implementation-defined" in C but see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7826402/1076479. Finally, it's possible that a pointer value passed as an argument, but then interpreted as an integer could be different than the same pointer that was then *converted* to an integer (especially considering byte-ordering concerns). Hence, explicit conversion is safer.