# Passing argument as int to thread - Warning: cast to pointer from integer different size

Tags: c, pthreads

What is the difference between passing an argument to **pthread_create** as int instead of long?

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
          const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
          void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *restrict arg);
```

I took the code from [POSIX Threads Programming](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Pthread) and it works only declaring the function argument as long

```
void *PrintHello(void *threadid) {
    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadid;
    printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;
    for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++){
        printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
        if (rc){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    /* Last thing that main() should do */
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: strictly speaking, I don't believe one should be casting either `int` or `long` to/from `void *`.  If you want to convert a `void *` to an integral type, you should be using `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Although even the `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` types are specified to be able to convert from a valid `void` pointer and back.  Nothing about taking just any value and creating a `void` pointer from it.  Really, casting like this is lazy hack and probably amounts to undefined behavior.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons It is not undefined behavior.  Per [**https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5**, paragraphs 5 and 6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5): "5 An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, **the result is implementation-defined**, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation."

Comment: (cont, para 6) "6 Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, **the result is implementation-defined**. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type. "

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ah, thank you for that reference.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons You're welcome.  Converting `int` values to and from `void *` under POSIX (the use of `pthread_create()` being informative...), is generally a hack that is going to "work" as long as the `int` values fit into a `void *` value, barring platform-specific limitations. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822904/is-it-always-safe-to-convert-an-integer-value-to-void-and-back-again-in-posix  But yeah, it's a hack.  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the issue has nothing to do with threads, but with the conversion between `void *` and integer types. 'c' allows you to freely convert across these types, but you have to pay attention to the sizes of the objects that you convert.

For example, on x86 in 64-bit mode the size of the `void*` is 64 bit (8 bytes). It is the same as the size of `long int`. However, size of `int` is 32 bits (4 bytes).

So, conversion of an `int` to `(void*)` will sign-extend int to 64 bits and assign it to void. Compiler gives you a warning, because sizes in the conversion are different but there is o violation of the standard here.

Conversion back to `int` from `void *` will also generate a warning. This conversion will loose upper 32 bits. But it will convert it correctly to `int`, if the `void *` itself was assigned from an int. However, if you try to convert it to `long` and the original `int` was negative, you will get a completely different picture, it will not be the same as the original `int`, all upper 32 bits will be a result of the original sign extension.

To make the picture more interesting, it will work differently on different platforms. For example, on 32-bit platforms size of `long int` could be the same as the size of `int` and the size of `void*`.

Potentially size of `long int` usually matches the size of `void*`. At least it does for a few platforms. Therefore this conversion is the safest one.

So, the best solution is to avoid such conversions when you write a cross-platform code.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to c and this stuff give me some trouble

Answer (score 0):

Your are treating the argument as a `long` rather than a pointer to `long`. This means you are depending on `long` and `void *` to have the same data size. If `int` has a different size this could explain why it goes wrong. In any case you should pass `&t` in the argument and extract it accordingly as `*threadid`:

```
void *PrintHello(void *threadid) {
    long tid;
    tid = *((long *)threadid); 
    printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    static long tid[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;
    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
        tid[t] = t;
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)&tid[t]);
        if(rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    /* Last thing that main() should do */
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Update: Store thread IDs in array `tid`.

Comment: I don't believe the size of `int` vs `long` should be an issue since there's no pointer dereferencing happening.

Comment: Have you tried running your code? I don't think it will produce the expected result.

Comment: The code works, you don’t need to use &. The problem is using int instead of long

Comment: @federico what kind of problem have you discovered? if you pass something as `(void *)int` and then cast it to `(void*)long` you should expect to have trash in the upper part of the `long`. Cast it to `int` instead.

Comment: All the threads get passed a pointer to the same variable. This makes no sense when using `t` as thread ID

Comment: @Serge Actually it's not an error, it's a warning, but I want to know why is throwing that. Pointer to integer of different size

Comment: @Christian Gibbons You are right it should not be an issue. My main point is that casting an integer (or long) to the `void *` argument is risky so it is much better to pass a pointer to whichever data type is needed.

Comment: @federico What is exactly the warning you get with the `int`?

Comment: @nielsen Warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
This is not happening when you use long

Comment: Run your code and watch what happens. The main thread may actually advance t a couple of times before the newly created threads print the value stored at t. So I think in this case passing the adress is a bad idea.

Comment: @sergeyrar You are right, I updated the code to store the thread IDs in an array. Thanks for noticing this.

Comment: @federico Then that _is_ the problem. The `int` type has a different size than `void *` on your machine (you can verify that by printing `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(void *)`. If you pass pointers as I show above, you can change the type of the `tid` array in `main()` and the `tid`variable in `PrintHello()` to `int`.

Comment: After changing `long t` into `long tid[]`, the code works, but it fails to answer the posters question. Neither does it improve the posters code.

Comment: @HAL9000 That is your subjective opinion. I do not agree, but this is not a discussion forum. The point of my answer is that the problem in the question comes from passing non-pointer data in a pointer-type argument and hence I show how to avoid that. The accepted answer from Serge explains this in more detail and makes the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. cleans up after itself, even when an error occurs
4. properly (using `perror()`) outputs the OPs error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.
5. uses the signature: `int main( void )` so no messages from the compiler about unused parameters.
6. Since a loop counter cannot be < 0, uses variable type `size_t` for the loop counter.
7. properly initializes (to 0) the `pthread_t` array to 0 so can be used for cleanup operations
8. Corrects the format specifiers in the calls to `printf()` to expect a variable with type: `size_t`
9. Has the `main()` function properly wait for the threads to exit before the `main()` function exits
10. incorporates a new function: `cleanup()` to properly cleanup any threads before exiting the program.
11. uses appropriate horizontal spacing and vertical spacing for readability and ease of understanding.

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 20


void *PrintHello( void *arg ) 
{
    size_t threadNum = (size_t)arg;

    printf( "Hello World! It's me, thread #%lu!\n", threadNum );
    pthread_exit( NULL );
} 



void cleanup( pthread_t *threads )
{
    for( size_t i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        if( threads[i] )
        {
            pthread_join( threads[i], NULL );
        }
    }
}


int main( void ) 
{
    pthread_t threads[ NUM_THREADS ] = {0};


    for( size_t t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++ )
    {
        printf( "In main: creating thread %ld\n", t );
        if( pthread_create( &threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t ) )
        {
            perror( "pthread_create() failed" );
            cleanup( threads );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    cleanup( threads );
    /* Last thing that main() should do */
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}
```

here is the output from a typical run of the proposed code when no errors occur:

```
In main: creating thread 0
In main: creating thread 1
Hello World! It's me, thread #0!
In main: creating thread 2
In main: creating thread 3
In main: creating thread 4
Hello World! It's me, thread #3!
In main: creating thread 5
Hello World! It's me, thread #4!
In main: creating thread 6
In main: creating thread 7
Hello World! It's me, thread #6!
Hello World! It's me, thread #5!
In main: creating thread 8
Hello World! It's me, thread #7!
In main: creating thread 9
Hello World! It's me, thread #8!
In main: creating thread 10
In main: creating thread 11
In main: creating thread 12
Hello World! It's me, thread #10!
Hello World! It's me, thread #9!
Hello World! It's me, thread #11!
In main: creating thread 13
In main: creating thread 14
Hello World! It's me, thread #13!
In main: creating thread 15
Hello World! It's me, thread #12!
Hello World! It's me, thread #14!
In main: creating thread 16
Hello World! It's me, thread #15!
In main: creating thread 17
In main: creating thread 18
In main: creating thread 19
Hello World! It's me, thread #19!
Hello World! It's me, thread #16!
Hello World! It's me, thread #17!
Hello World! It's me, thread #18!
Hello World! It's me, thread #1!
Hello World! It's me, thread #2!
```